# How add button control on frame or panel at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

windows form application
I want desine keypad like pda device .I want all numeric keys in one group therfore I  want to arrange all these button on one frame or panel . second frame or panel which contain all the special function keys . I want design this keyboard at runtime after reading xml file description of keypad.
 please guide me to implement this.

Comment: Are you talking about webforms (asp.net), asp.net mvc, or winforms (desktop apps)?

Answer (score 10):

Short version of adding a control to a container (`Button` used as example):

```
   Button myButton = new Button();
   myButton.Text = "some text";
   // attach event handler for Click event 
   // (assuming ButtonClickHandler is an existing method in the class)
   myButton.Click += ButtonClickHandler;
   myPanel.Controls.Add(myButton);
   // additional code for setting location and such for myButton
```

The tricky part will probably not be to create the controls and add them to the container, but to arrange them so that it looks good.

Comment: Dynamically adding controls to a form can indeed be a layout nightmare; fortunately, there's the TableLayoutPanel control to make things (a bit) easier.

Answer (score 1):

another example add 5 button

```
    int xlocation = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
         Button newButton = new Button();
         {
             newButton.Name = string.Format("Button{0}", i);
             newButton.Text = string.Format("Button {0}",i);
             newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xlocation, 10);
             newButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 35);
             newButton.Click += btn_msg;
             this.Controls.Add(newButton);
         }
         xlocation = xlocation + 85;
    }
```

button click **Event**

```
    public void btn_msg(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        conn.msgErr(btn.Name.ToString());
    }
```